# System can't see ServerRAID M1015 virtual drive?

Tags: raid, sas, mirror, ibm

We connected the card to our system and have created a new mirror RAID 1 virtual drive, Now we want to clone our existing single drive to this new virtual drive, but our cloning software Acronis True Image Server doesn't see it.

We also don't see the SAS controller in BIOS boot order.

Any idea how to make the drive visible to system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boot off the SAS controller could come under "external device" or similar heading in the BIOS. You can also call IBM support, they should be able to tell you, how to set this up.

The checklist to run:

1. Is the controller supported by your server? Check e.g. here: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/tips0740.html
2. Is the controller supported by your cloning software? Check the producer's website and check hardware compatibility list for your version of the software.

You could also try Clonezilla. Support for ServeRAID has been in Linux kernels for ages now and it should be able to do the job for you.

Comment: Hi. 1) Server model is x206m (8485EAY), and while it not listed in the link above, it does boots normally and allows creating new virtual drive.

Comment: After creating the new virtual drive, we want to select it as boot drive, but there is no boot order in BIOS, there is boot menu (F12) which doesn't contain the virtual drive. 2) Acronis Echo Server should be supporting this card - we will try with latest version. Also, we will give a look to the Clonezilla you have mentioned.

Comment: Clonezilla does the trick - wish other software would start support LSI/ServeRaid too!